# How does a timeslot reservation app handle concurrent timeslot section problem using Databases?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Databases and learning about DynamoDB in AWS. While I read through the basic GET/POST functionality of databases, I came across a tricky problem which is already solved in real world.

**Problem statement:** 
Let's say there are two timeslots, `t1` and `t2` that users on an app can choose and book. What I am trying to understand is that how to solve a problem when User A, and User B are both trying to book timeslot `t1`. Ideally only one of them should succeed, and the other one should get an error. Let's say the booking flow is: `slot selection` -> `payment` -> `booking success`. So, there is a finite amount of time between `slot selection` and `booking success`, and also User could choose to just exit in the middle of the flow.

**What seems like could work:**

- When User A does `slot selection` for `t1`, the app writes to the database a `current timestamp` and also a `status` variable that goes from `active` to `reserved`.
- A user is only allowed to go from `slot selection` to `payment` when the `status` of the timeslot is seen as `active`. Otherwise, throw an error.

**What I am not sure of:**

- What's the best way to build the database table in this case? Meaning, should I keep a `status` bit with each `timeslot` ?
- How do I implement a timeout functionality, which controls that a user has to go from `slot selection` to `booking success` within `x` minutes, or else they can't choose that slot anymore and the `status` will change from `reserved` to `active`.

Does anyone have suggestions on how professional system designers would implement this efficiently? I am using DynamoDB.

Comment: Read about databases and concurrency, including optimistic locking, distributed locks, ACID vs BASE, eventual consistency, and more.